# jQuery autosuggest plugin not displaying results

Tags: jquery

I'm using [the plugin by Drew Wilon](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin) to search a DB table of city names when the user starts typing to a text field. Via Firebug I can see that data is returned in proper JSON format. So AFAIK everything is working ok on the PHP end.

When results are returned, they should be displayed in a div below the textfield. I can see this div in Firebug but it remains empty. It used to work fine so I'm thinking it's a small gotcha that I'm just not seeing.

How can I get the results to display in this div?

Test page is [here](http://sub.domain.com/user/signup) - in the middle column is a City field. Type for example "ham" and you'll see the returned data in JSON format in Firebug.

JS:

```
$("input#city").autoSuggest("http://sub.domain.com/survey/search_city", {
            selectedItemProp: "response", 
            selectedValuesProp: "id", 
            searchObjProps: "response",
            startText: "",
            minChars: 2,
            selectionLimit: 1,  
        });
```

Returned JSON sample

```
[{"response":"Hamilton (Victoria, Australia)","id":"18860_14"},{"response":"Hamilton (Hamilton Municipality, Bermuda)","id":"6042_27"},{"response":"Hamilton (Ontario, Canada)","id":"3460_43"},{"response":"Hami (Xinjiang, China)","id":"6156_49"},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing i could see would be

```
$("input#city").autoSuggest("http://kms.rubypseudo.com/survey/search_city", {
            selectedItemProp: "response", 
            selectedValuesProp: "id", 
            searchObjProps: "response",
            startText: "",
            minChars: 2,
            selectionLimit: 1,  
        });
```

got a Comma after "selectionLimit: 1" and it should not.

that would break your parameter json therefor break the plugin

i checked it out again and realized that there is an incompatibility with the autoSuggest and the jquery.validate.js plugin ... if you remove it your autocomplete will work . it got something to do with the $.getJSON... never completing when you got both addon

Comment: You're right, there is an incompatiblity between this plugin and the validation plugin.